# Is the "Gets or sets .." necessary in XML documentation of properties?

Tags: c#, .net, programming-practices, comments

I am looking for a recommendation of a best practice for XML comments in C#. When you create a property, it seems like that the expected XML documentation has the following form:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the ID the uniquely identifies this <see cref="User" /> instance.
/// </summary>
public int ID {
    get;
    set;
}
```

But since the signature of the property already tells you what operations are available to the external clients of the class (in this case it is both `get` and `set`) I feel like the comments are too chatty and that perhaps the following would be sufficient:

```
/// <summary>
/// ID that uniquely identifies this <see cref="User" /> instance.
/// </summary>
public int ID {
    get;
    set;
}
```

Microsoft uses the first form so it seems like it is an implied convention. But I think that the second one is better for the reasons I stated.

I understand that this quetion is an adept for being marked as not being constructive, but the amount of properties that one has to comment is huge and so I believe that this question has its right to be here.

I will appreciate any ideas or links to official recommended practices.

Comment: honestly the only thing the comment gives me that isn't in the code (assuming this is a member of User) is that the id is unique. so none of it is 'necessary'.

Comment: @Tomas - have you installed the [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) plugin? it will generate good XML comments for you if you use good property names to start with and automatically put the `gets or sets` or `gets` depending on the property accessors.

Comment: @Trevor - I do have it installed. I was just thinking whether I should change its templates and remove the "Gets or sets" or not :). It is a great plugin though.

Comment: Welcome to the world of [*undocumentation*](http://blog.codinghorror.com/avoiding-undocumentation/).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The signature may tell other pieces of code what operations are available; however, they are not clearly shown to the coder as he or she is working and XML documentation is meant for people to consume and not a compiler.

Take this class for example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The first one
    /// </summary>
    public int GetOrSet { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The second one
    /// </summary>
    public int GetOnly { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The last one
    /// </summary>
    public int SetOnly { set; private get; }
}
```

When intellisense is pulled up to access one of these properties there is no indication which ones can be written to, read from, or both:

[image]

Likewise when viewing the documentation we also aren't quite sure:

[image]
[image]
[image]

As such we add the *gets or sets*, *gets*, or *sets* to make it easier on the programmer while writing the code. It certainly would not be write a large block of code that reads and processes some data only to find out that you cannot write that data back to the property as expected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for a thorough answer. I think that these are unfortunately limitations of the Visual Studio IDE. I have thought about it and I think that the intellisense could show you which properties are, e.g., `get`-only in the current context. It is not very convenient to bend the documentation to fit a particular development environment. Still I think that Visual Studio and C# are so closely related that this just might be the right solution.

Comment: @Tomas I agree that Visual Studio should make more of a distinction. It certainly is happy to give me a red squiggly line the second I use the property improperly.

Comment: The problem you've provided is a problem of Visual Studio UI, not the comments

Answer (score 3):

StyleCop uses the `Gets or Sets ...` notation which it enforces with rule [SA1623](http://stylecop.soyuz5.com/SA1623.html).

The linked page lists another case you haven't listed:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a value indicating whether the item is enabled.
/// </summary>
public bool Enabled
{
    get { return this.enabled; }
}
```

The other option you list would be.

```
/// <summary>
/// ID that uniquely identifies this <see cref="User" /> instance.
/// </summary>
public int ID { get; set; }
```

vs

```
/// <summary>
/// ID that uniquely identifies this <see cref="User" /> instance.
/// </summary>
public int ID { get; }
```

Which wouldn't provide information on the Intellisense hint that the property is read only, you could come up with a convention for this case too, but `Gets ...`, `Gets or Sets...` does the job nicely imo.

There are also other varients listed on the StyleCop rule which are clear by using the `Gets or Sets...` but might not be without.

Also when generating documentation from something like Doxygen or Sandcastle the full notation would document the API (for example) better.

Answer (score 2):

The only time I add information about the getting and setting of a property in the XML comments is when it doesn't behave as expected (straight public get and set).

If either are private or if they contain additional logic then I mention them, otherwise I just document the intent of the property.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be happier with the more verbose version.

The other is like having a comment of "increment counter" after, well, incrementing a counter variable.

It is obvious there is a Get and Set. If you had a private setter, it'd be obvious as you would have the private keyword.

Comments should add value, not just be comment version of what the code actually is.